# Growing a flex div inside a Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 Bootstrap `cols`, one of which contains some large text. The other one contains a few `div`s. I want to make one of the `div`s flex-grow in such a way so it will fill the entire space, making both `col`s equally high.

This is a demo showing what I want to do: http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/mJLraW

The element that contains the text `2` should grow, pushing the rest of the elements down.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Please write this as an answer so I can down-vote it properly :)

Comment: sorry? what do you mean? Can I not even give you a suggestion?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal This was an obvious troll, that's why you removed your comment. But even if it wasn't a troll, I'd still down-vote it as "use jquery..." is rather rubbish for what I'm asking here.

Comment: I mistakenly removed my comment. But I see this kind of question many times and the solution for this with css (ummm --- what ---- ummm), so I said you to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: flex; /* this */
}
```

It allows the two columns inside the row to be come the same height.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xGjRPR)